# Backreference regular expressions Unix

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I really don't understand how I can use these backreferences. Let me give you an example:

```
grep '\([a-z]\)\([a-z]\)[a-z]\2\1'
```

The instruction before finds the palindrome words in a file. But I don't understand how it works? What's with all these `\2\1` and why aren't they `\1\2`?

Comment: This regular expression matches ***ONLY 5-letter palindromes***.

Answer (score 5):

simple explain it with example:

`\2\1` will match text like: `foxof`

here:

```
f o  x  o  f
| |     \2 \1
| |_2
|
|_1
```

`\1\2` will match text like: `foxfo`

so you see the different

Answer (score 4):

the \1 is the first match inside the parentheses 
the \2 is the second match

so you're looking for

```
(any char)(another char)[a middle char](the second char again)(the first char again)
  ([a-z])    ([a-z])        [a-z]               \2                   \1
```

Answer (score 1):

The "\2" references the second pair of parentheses and the "\1" references the first. It's "\2\1" rather than "\1\2" because, otherwise, it wouldn't be a palindrome.

Comment: @SteveEmerson I still don't get it. I searched everywhere on the internet to find some good explanation on backreferences and I didn't find anything. Can you explain me the mechanism? How does it compare and everything else?

Comment: The first parentheses save whatever character was matched in a temp location called `1`. The second parentheses save the second character, whatever it is, in a location called `2`. The backreference `\1` matches if the character at that spot is the same as whatever was saved earlier in location `1`. Ditto for the `\2` backreference.